# ToolbarAndroid action in overflow menu

Tags: android, react-native

I got a problem. I'm using ToolbarAndroid, and I want my actions to appear in overflow menu. Im sending my actions like that:

```
actions={this.getToolbarActions()}

    getToolbarActions() {
      let actions = [];
      if (!isEmpty(this.props.authReducer.user)) {
        actions.push({
          icon: 'exit-to-app',
          title: 'LogOut',
          onPress: this.logOut,
          show: 'never',
        });
      }
      else {
        actions.push({
          icon: 'account-circle',
          title: 'LogIn',
          onPress: this.logIn,
          show: 'never'
        });
      }
      return actions;
    }
```

But actions are always shown. I triend to set `show` to `always`, `ifRoom`, `never` - nothing. It's always shown there. Even when I added about 50 actions, it's always visible. Some1 can help me?

Comment: react-native version?

Comment: @V-SHY 0.21 right now

Comment: try change icon declaration to icon: require('./exit-to-app') and  icon: require('./account-circle') and react-native run-android again?

Comment: Nah, still nothing. :/ even after changing icon problem still exists.